# Can I output csh.xml via Docbook Export in Robohelp 10

Tags: xml, xhtml, docbook, robohelp, help-authoring

Can I output a context sensitive help file, "Project_Name_csh.xml" via Docbook Export in Robohelp 10?

The file is not generated when using the 'export project to DocBook' Handler from XML_Output SSL.

However, it is generated when using 'Export Project to XHTML' from the XML_Output SSL, this format is not useful as this has mixed '.htm' files and links associated with it.

I will need to generate all help files as xml output including Context Sensitive Help (including map/topic ids) for consumption in various applications.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question properly. But sounds like appart from the DocBook export you can create you like to have a context sensitive help file (csf). Is the info in a csf available in the exported docbook file(s)? If so, you probably want to have a XSL which extract the info and creates the required csf.